# How much will a sheet of paper bend in a following situation?

Tags: everyday-life, elasticity

Imagine a sheet of paper (or any other elastic material) of length $l$, width $d$ and thickness $s$. It's placed partially hanging from the edge of a table (n% of it's lenght is loose), pressed between a block and the table. How to find the position of the hanging end of the sheet relatively to the edge of the table (see the sketch)? [image]
I’m not specifying the constants of the material, because I’m not sure which ones are necessary.

Comment: You'll need strain-stress numbers or the elastic modulus for the paper.

Comment: What are the elastic constant of the paper? You need them to solve the problem.

Comment: To elaborate on the previous comments:  this can probably be treated as a problem in *beam theory*.  Look into either [Euler-Bernoulli beam theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler–Bernoulli_beam_theory) or (more likely) its big brother [Timoshenko-Ehrenfest beam theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timoshenko–Ehrenfest_beam_theory).

Comment: I’ve not specified them because I didn’t know which constants are necessary for the calculation (perhaps there are other elasticity constants apart from Young’s modulus). Please, use the parameters that you think are needed (you may not use specific values for paper).

Comment: @michael seifert thanks, I’ll check and try to apply it.

Comment: Note that if you cut two strips of paper from the same sheet, in different directions you'll get different results.  What you have is a classic way of determining grain direction in paper...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you could cut stripes in different direction to characterize the Young modulus.

Using the expression for an Euler-Bernoulli beam you have the following

$$y = \frac{q x^4}{8EI}\, ,$$

where $q = \rho A g$ is the load, $E$ is the Young modulus, $I$ is the second moment of area, $\rho$ is the mass density and $A$ is the cross-sectional area. Rewriting you get

$$y = \frac{3 gx^4}{2Ed^2}\, ,$$

and you can solve for $E$

$$E = \frac{3 gx^4}{2yd^2}\, .$$

Once you characterize the Young modulus for a particular direction you can use the cantilever solution with that particular Young modulus.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I’m now gonna go through all the background theory about strain to derive this equation, cause this whole topic is pretty much unfamiliar to me.